# c# visual studio Summarry

Tags: c#, summary

```
/// <summary>
/// Some Code PLS
/// </summary>
/// <param name="HKEY">0CurrentUser, 1LocalMachine, 2ClassesRoot, 3Users, 4CurrentConfig</param>
/// <param name="keypath">dqw</param>
/// <param name="keyname">dqwq</param>
/// <param name="keyvalue">dw1q</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static void Create(int HKEY, string keypath, string keyname, int keyvalue)
```

This is my **.dll** code. I use in other project with "**using MFG.dll**". I cant see summary other project. It's only shown in dll project.

This is in project:

[image: Screenshot Function description]

Comment: You don't have anything in the summary tags, of course nothing will show. Also your param names are empty and should have something in them.

Comment: now isnt empty. But when i use this method in other project, i cant see summary pop

Comment: Not quite sure, long time since I used summaries, but I believe you have to copy the XML documentation file along with the DLL file so it can display the intellisense.

Comment: thnks. i found anser, below. go settings and check "xml doc file" setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cant see summary other project

The visual reason for this is because your `<summary>` tags are empty, they will not show a summary.

```
/// <summary>
/// IM EMPTY!!!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="HKEY">0CurrentUser, 1LocalMachine, 2ClassesRoot, 3Users, 4CurrentConfig</param>
/// <param name="keypath"></param>
/// <param name="keyname"></param>
/// <param name="keyvalue"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

To fix this you need to include a summary (text) of the routine; you also need to include the summary of your arguments. For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// My routine!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="HKEY">My HKEY</param>
/// <param name="keypath">The keypath</param>
/// <param name="keyname">The actual keyname</param>
/// <param name="keyvalue">The value of the key</param>
public static void Create(int HKEY, string keypath, string keyname, int keyvalue)
```

Another thing worth checking is that you have an `XML Documentation` file. If it's missing, there's no way to map them.

-> Right-click on the project and select Properties. In the properties dialog, select the Build tab, and check XML documentation file.

For more information, please visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc) on related documents.

Comment: Yep. I gone settings and do that. Now it's working well

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your comments in the text of the tag, like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates something or other.  
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="HKEY">0 = CurrentUser, 1 = LocalMachine, 2 = ClassesRoot, 3 = Users, 4 = CurrentConfig</param>
    /// <param name="keypath">The key path.</param>
    /// <param name="keyname">The key name.</param>
    /// <param name="keyvalue">The key value</param>
    public static void Create(int HKEY, string keypath, string keyname, int keyvalue)
```

I have removed the returns tag as this method returns void (no return value).